# How do I make an API call with data from an asynchronous data stream (observable)?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am writing an Angular 2 book search app that interacts with an API via the app's services. I have a form for users to upload books to the database on the backend, on submit the `uploadBook` function is run:

```
uploadBook(){
    //collects form data and uses it to set the value of this.book

    this._uploadService.uploadBookToDb(this.book)
        .subscribe( res => {
            alert('book uploaded');
        })
  }
```

In `upload.service.ts`:

```
uploadBookToDb(book){
    return this._http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/book_new', JSON.stringify(book))
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

This works fine and I get a response from the server like normal. However I run into trouble when I try to do a book lookup as the user types:

```
bookTitle.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .map(bookTitle => this._uploadService.bookLookUp(bookTitle))
        .subscribe(res => update dropdown with results);
```

In the service `bookLookup` is similar to the working `uploadBookToDb` above:

```
bookLookUp(title){
    return this._http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/book_lookup', JSON.stringify(title))
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

However when I type in the book title field, the observable itself is returned: `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`. There is no activity recorded on the server i.e the API call in the service is not even being executed at all.

I am sure that I am wrongly mapping the observable to the service but am confused about how to do this properly when dealing with async data requests like in the case of `valueChanges`. Any help figuring this out would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to the observable returned by `bookLookUp(title)`.. somewhere.

Not sure about your exact version but if you are using 5+, use `HttpClient` instead of full `Http` and remove `.map(res => res.json());` - that's not necessary anymore.

Comment: This is what I am attempting to do with ```bookTitle.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .map(bookTitle => this._uploadService.bookLookUp(bookTitle))
        .subscribe(res => {books = res});```

Comment: Well, then subscribe to the value changes? You have commented out the subscription there, why?

Comment: Sorry that was rather misleading, commented it out cause I haven't written out the function in it yet but in my code I have subscribed to valueChanges without .subscribe commented out

Comment: Would you care to correct the code in the question then? Try also change `map` to `switchMap` operator in the `bookTitle.valueChanges`

Comment: Thank you, `switchMap` worked! Now trying to understand why it worked over `map`, is it because it cancels the previously subscribed observable and prevents some sort of pipeline buildup that disrupts the operation?